# css navigation bar not appearing horizontally at top of page on same line as logo

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get my css navigation bar to appear on the same line as my logo.  I am guessing that this has a simple enough solution but as a learner it seems to be some teething problems for me that unfortunately I cannot resolve.  Code from both css and html file are in the jsbin link below where you can get a full visual too:

https://jsbin.com/qopuqahute/edit?html,css,output

Your assistance and advice will be much appreciated.

### HTML

```
<div id= topbar>            
        <div id= logodiv>
            Tailored Web Solutions
        </div>            
        <div id="navigationbar">
             <ul>
                 <li> About Us </li>
                 <li> Services </li>
             </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

#topbar{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}

#logodiv{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navigationbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;

}

#navigationbar ul li{
    color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: And before making that effort, do a little search too. I'm sure I've seen this question been asked a couple of times before, so you could save yourself and us the work.

Comment: post your code, please! create jsfiddle-example with your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#logodiv` and `#navigationbar` are both divs which are by default block elements. To get them to line up use `display: inline-block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Leztux5k/

### CSS

```
#logodiv{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigationbar{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for this.  Your suggestion has resolved my issue.  Much appreciated and credit to you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

add a `float:left;` property to your `#logodiv` rule like this:

```
#logodiv{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: thank you, your suggestion also has helped me out too.